# Unable to Send Json Response with Jersey Maven Rest Services

Tags: java, json, maven, jersey-2.0

I'm working on a project where I need to write **web-services** in Java Jersey framework. Everything is working if I run web-services using **IntelliJ**. But If I make jar of my java program and run it using the **cmd**. My web-services throws exception when sending back Json Response.

Below is Exception.

> AM org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor aroundWriteTo
>   SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class response.BaseResponse, genericType=class response.BaseResponse.

I added the Jersey media json dependency in pom.file also.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
   <version>2.26</version>
</dependency>
```

And below is **BaseResponse** class for Json response.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class BaseResponse {

    public static final int SUCCESS = 1;
    public static final int FAILURE = 0;

    private int status;
    private String message;

    BaseResponse() {
    }

    public BaseResponse(int status, String message) {
        this.status = status;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BaseResponse{" +
                "status=" + status +
                ", message='" + message + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Also one thing more that I create the jar file using the **maven-shade-plugin** which creates a fat uber jar.

Comment: Did you forget to add the ServicesResourceTransformer?

Comment: Thanks, @PaulSamsotha for marked as duplicate. The linked question facing the same problem and it really helped me.